# MRUNIT java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: hadoop

When am running the test case I am getting this exception

```
 java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.mock.MockContextWrapper.createCommon(MockContextWrapper.java:53)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.mock.MockMapContextWrapper.create(MockMapContextWrapper.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.mock.MockMapContextWrapper.<init>(MockMapContextWrapper.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.MapDriver.run(MapDriver.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.MapDriverBase.runTest(MapDriverBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.TestDriver.runTest(TestDriver.java:137)
    at konnectMR.konnect.mr.MRTestOne.testMapper(MRTestOne.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTestMethod(MethodRoadie.java:98)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:79)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:77)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Here is POM Dependecies

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3-alpha</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3-alpha</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0-incubating</version>
    <classifier>hadoop1</classifier> 
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0-incubating</version>
    <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

You add two "org.apache.mrunit" dependencies. The first "org.apache.mrunit" is active. And it's the hadoop1 api. Since you are using hadoop2, you need to remove the first dependency of "org.apache.mrunit". Remove the following content:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0-incubating</version>
    <classifier>hadoop1</classifier> 
</dependency>
```

Considering mrunit is only used for unit tests. You can change the second dependency to the following content:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0-incubating</version>
    <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove one of your final two dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0-incubating</version>
    <classifier>hadoop1</classifier> 
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0-incubating</version>
    <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Depending on the version of Hadoop you are using, keep the dependency with the corresponding classfier (hadoop1 or hadoop2) and remove the other.

Also, consider using a newer version of MRUnit, 1.1.0 was released in June of 2014.